# Selenium webdriver dropdown selection using classname

Tags: jquery, selenium

```
<div class="k-list-scroller" unselectable="on" style="height: 200px;">
<ul id="Salutation_listbox" class="k-list k-reset" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox">
<li id="c77e68b5-ded1-48a8-932c-74a5b2f45c66" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" data-offset-index="0" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Salutation</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="1" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" style="">Mr</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="2" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Mrs</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="3" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Miss</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="4" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Ms</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="5" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Dr</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="6" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Prof</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="7" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Rev</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

This is a salutation drop down, I need to select the Mr from the drop down values. My code is incomplete I don't know how to write a script for it, but my code is as follows,

```
driver.findElement(By.className("k-input")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.className("k-item")).click();
driver.findElement(By.tagName("Mr")).click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a [KendoUI DropDown](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index)

You have to first click on the dropdown element.Could be `span` or `div`

I have taken the Demo Site to demsonstrate how you can select the values

I'm going to select `Orange` value from `Cap Color` DropDown

[image]

As you can see the element is `span` with class `k-widget k-dropdown k-header`.

You have to click on that first. Then only you'll get the ul list populated.

From that you can select any `k-item` by using the simple xpath.

> //ul[@id='idOfUl']/li[@class='k-item' and text()='itemName']

For you it should be

> //ul[@id='Salutation_listbox']/li[@class='k-item' and text()='Mr']

**Sample Code**

```
public void testKendo() {
        driver.get("http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index");

        String capColorDropDown = "//span[@role='listbox']";

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(capColorDropDown)).click();

        String itemName = "Orange";

        String listId = "color_listbox";

        String xpathForItem = "//ul[@id='" + listId + "']/li[@class='k-item' and text()='" + itemName + "']";

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathForItem)).click();

        driver.quit();
    }
```

Comment: @user3836485 Then you can [accept it  as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you requirement is accessing the element through classname. so i have modified it as xpath with attributes as class and text contained in it.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getelementsbyclassname('k-list-scroller').setAttribute('unselectable', 'off')");
js.executeScript("document.getelementsbyclassname('k-list k-reset').setAttribute('unselectable', 'off')");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='Mr'and class='k-item']")).click();
```

Comment: While executing this comment i am getting the error message as, unknown error:document.getelementsbyclassname is not a function

Comment: It should be `getElementsByClassName`