# How to select a value from Kendo UI MVVM drop down in automated test?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, kendo-mvvm

Could anyone please help me with selecting a value from Kendo UI MVVM drop down using Selenium Java?

```
<input class="k-input fieldFullWidth" autocomplete="off" style="width: 100%;" title="" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-owns="ddStore_listbox" type="text">

<input id="ddStore" class="fieldFullWidth" data-role="combobox" style="display: none;" aria-disabled="false" data-bind="value: selectedAsset.StoreID, comboboxText: selectedAsset.StoreName">
```

I tried to use JavascriptExecutor. But, it gives me org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot set property 'value' of null error.

```
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('ddstore').value = '1';");
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean javascript tag? and not java

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention. I am using Selenium Java to do automated test

Comment: I think its a combo box, Please add UI image as well

Comment: UI image: http://www.screencast.com/t/8Zj7fYgDks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium webdriver dropdown selection using classname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593488/selenium-webdriver-dropdown-selection-using-classname)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExplicitWait` to wait until visibility of `<input>`tag element and then send your dropdown value as input

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ddStore")));

driver.findElement(By.id("ddStore")).sendKeys("dropDown_Value"); // send your dropdown value as input
```

`

The another alternative way is to use `JavascriptExecuter` as your tag  contains attribute `style="display: none;"` so might be changes of invisibility of element

```
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='your_dropdown_value';",driver.findElement(By.id("ddStore")));
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It gives me the following error org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 120 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: ddStore

Comment: Ok, do try this if you want to do this using `JavaScriptExecuter` - `jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='your_dropdown';", driver.findElement(By.id("ddStore")));`

Comment: No error in the console. But, no value can be enter on the drop down box either - http://www.screencast.com/t/N15vzoTub

Comment: I don't know why it causing problem at your end. can you try to add some pause before and after this statement like `Thread.sleep(3000)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to select dropdown value:

```
Select mydrpdwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddStore"))); //id of dropdown  
mydrpdwn.selectByVisibleText("name");// Value you wanted to select
```